# density curve plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am new in ggplot and I am trying to draw a density curve.
This is a simplified version of the code that I am trying to use:

```
ggplot(data=ind1, aes(ind1$V1)) + 
geom_density(fill = "red", colour = "black") + xlim(0, 30)
```

The density curve plot that I get looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yxted.jpg)

I do not understand what is wrong here! does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: You probably have too many observations on each of those integer values and nothing in between then, wich creates this very dense peaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the adjust parameter.

```
 ggplot(data=iris, aes(iris$Sepal.Length)) + 
 geom_density(fill = "red", colour = "black",adjust=3) + xlim(0, 30)
```

Just so you can compare how the parameter affects the smoothing:

```
 ggplot(data=iris, aes(iris$Sepal.Length)) + 
 geom_density(fill = "red", colour = "black",adjust=1/2) + xlim(0, 30)
```

Try a couple different values (I think a little greater than 1 will produce the result you want).

Comment: Thanks so much@VictorFreg. yes it worked quite well with adjust = 4!